# Is it possible for a purely user-space bug to cause a system_call_fastpath() segfault in Linux?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, kernel, system-calls

While testing on one of our Linux boxes, we saw our user-space program stop functioning, and the debug-output listed below was printed to the Linux's box's serial port.

My belief is that this problem indicates either a buggy Linux kernel, a buggy kernel-mode driver, or buggy hardware, but I'd like to confirm:  is it true that due to Linux's MMU/memory-protection feature, it ought to be impossible for a user-mode program to cause this failure, and therefore the existence of this failure indicates that there must be a problem at either the kernel or hardware level?

OTOH if it is possible for a user-mode program to induce this on a healthy Linux box, I'd be interested in details of any known mechanism(s) by which that might occur.

```
[  513.939323] redactedd[2619]: segfault at 48f0246f ip 00007f11adf0ea45 sp 00007fff238f05b8 error 6 in libc-2.7.so[7f11ade97000+14a000]
[  513.965679] redactedd[2493]: segfault at 48f024f3 ip 00007f0b09ea2a45 sp 00007fff6d0537d8 error 6 in libc-2.7.so[7f0b09e2b000+14a000]
[  513.997520] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
[  514.001002] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:04:00.0/port_control_monitor
[  514.001002] CPU 2   
[  514.001002] Modules linked in: bonding adt7475 redacted_fpga ioatdmart e1000e [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
[  514.001002] Pid: 2629, comm: redactedd Not tainted 2.6.31.8 #1 Redacted 09:58:40]   
[  514.001002] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8137c33b>]  
[  514.062841] Outputs Process[2644]: segfault at 8359f44 ip 00000000008c58d1 sp 000000004011f110 error 6 in redactedd[400000+153c000]
[  514.001002]  [<ffffffff8137c33b>] tcp_v4_destroy_sock+0xdb/0x1c0
[  514.001002] RSP: 0018:ffff88007d00bdb8  EFLAGS: 00010296
[  514.001002] RAX: ffffffff815b0120 RBX: ffff88007c959a00 RCX: ffffffff81367104
[  514.001002] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff88007c959b78 RDI: ffff00007c959ee0
[  514.001002] RBP: ffff88007c959ee0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000001
[  514.140837] redactedd[2667]: segfault at 60a76760 ip 00007f5660046c72 sp 00007fff82d80ac8 error 6 in libpthread-2.7.so[7f566003d000+16000]
[  514.140860] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000014 R12: ffff88004d136600
[  514.140860] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff88007c959fa0 R15: 00007f886c05ea30
[  514.140860] FS:  00007f8879e0f760(0000) GS:ffff880001731000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  514.140860] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  514.140860] CR2: 0000000048f024f3 CR3: 000000007d01c000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
[  514.140860] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  514.140860] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  514.140860] Process redactedd (pid: 2629, threadinfo ffff88007d00a000, task ffff88007e0e8000)
[  514.140860] Stack:
[  514.140860]  ffff88007c959a00 ffff88007c959a00 ffff88004d136600 ffffffff813d1fe9
[  514.140860] <0> ffff88007c959a00 ffffffff8136831a ffff88004d1144b0 ffffffff81375f3a
[  514.140860] <0> ffff88004d136600 ffff88007c959a00 ffff88004d1144b0 0000000000000000
[  514.140860] Call Trace:
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813d1fe9>] ? tcp_v6_destroy_sock+0x9/0x20
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8136831a>] ? inet_csk_destroy_sock+0x4a/0x130
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff81375f3a>] ? tcp_rcv_state_process+0x88a/0xc40
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813d2c6f>] ? tcp_v6_do_rcv+0x11f/0x3d0
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8133b97b>] ? __alloc_skb+0x6b/0x170
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813359ab>] ? release_sock+0x4b/0xa0
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8136aa89>] ? tcp_close+0x169/0x470
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8138b2ae>] ? inet_release+0x3e/0x70
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813336c1>] ? sock_release+0x21/0x90
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff81333742>] ? sock_close+0x12/0x30
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff811001ad>] ? __fput+0xcd/0x1e0
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff810fca9b>] ? filp_close+0x5b/0x90
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff810fcb76>] ? sys_close+0xa6/0x100
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8100bdbf>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  514.140860] Code: 00 00 00 ff 0f 00 00 0f 8f eb 00 00 00 48 8d ab e0 04 00 00 48 8b bb e0 04 00 00 48 39 fd 74 36 48 85 ff 74 31 ff 8b f0 04 00 00 <48> 8b 17 48 8b 47 08 48 c7 07 00 00 00 00 48 c7 47 08 00 00 00
[  514.140860] RIP  [<ffffffff8137c33b>] tcp_v4_destroy_sock+0xdb/0x1c0
[  514.140860]  RSP <ffff88007d00bdb8>
```

Answer (score 0):

This output indicates several segmentation faults in user-mode programs and a general protection fault.

**Segmentation faults** occur when a process attempts to access memory that it is not allowed to access, such as a null pointer or memory that has been freed.

**General protection faults** occur when a process attempts to operate that it does not have permission to do, such as WRITE to READ-ONLY memory page or accessing an I/O port that is reserved for privileged operations.

The fact that these faults are occurring in user-mode programs suggests that there may be a bug in the kernel or a hardware malfunction that allows the process to access memory or perform operations that they should not be allowed to do. For example, in a healthy Linux system, processes run in a protected memory space isolated from other processes and the kernel, which is managed by the Memory Management Unit (MMU) and memory protection features of the processor. This is designed to prevent processes from accessing memory or performing operations that they do not have permission to do.

Suppose a user-mode program can cause a system-wide failure. In that case, it could indicate that the kernel or hardware is not adequately enforcing memory protection and permission checks, which could be due to a bug in the kernel or a hardware malfunction. Alternatively (worse scenario), it could be a due to a malicious program that has found a vulnerability in the kernel or hardware and exploits it to gain elevated privileges.

To identify the root cause of the problem, it may be necessary to conduct a kernel log analysis/debugging to trace the execution of the program and identify the source of the faults. Hardware diagnostics may also be essential to determine if there is a hardware malfunction.

---

> Specifically my question is whether a crash inside system_call_fastpath() could occur on a system where the only problem is a bug that is present in a user-space program. –
> Jeremy Friesner

Yea, if a bug in a user-space program causes a crash that happens to occur within the kernel's `system_call_fastpath()` function, it can potentially cause the entire system to crash, although it is rare for this to happen. This can occur because this function is a critical part of the kernel responsible for handling system calls.

Let's quickly examine your `dmesg` snippet:

```
[  514.140860] Call Trace:
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813d1fe9>] ? tcp_v6_destroy_sock+0x9/0x20
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8136831a>] ? inet_csk_destroy_sock+0x4a/0x130
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff81375f3a>] ? tcp_rcv_state_process+0x88a/0xc40
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813d2c6f>] ? tcp_v6_do_rcv+0x11f/0x3d0
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8133b97b>] ? __alloc_skb+0x6b/0x170
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813359ab>] ? release_sock+0x4b/0xa0
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8136aa89>] ? tcp_close+0x169/0x470
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8138b2ae>] ? inet_release+0x3e/0x70
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff813336c1>] ? sock_release+0x21/0x90
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff81333742>] ? sock_close+0x12/0x30
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff811001ad>] ? __fput+0xcd/0x1e0
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff810fca9b>] ? filp_close+0x5b/0x90
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff810fcb76>] ? sys_close+0xa6/0x100
[  514.140860]  [<ffffffff8100bdbf>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  514.140860] Code: 00 00 00 ff 0f 00 00 0f 8f eb 00 00 00 48 8d ab e0 04 00 00 48 8b bb e0 04 00 00 48 39 fd 74 36 48 85 ff 74 31 ff 8b f0 04 00 00 <48> 8b 17 48 8b 47 08 48 c7 07 00 00 00 00 48 c7 47 08 00 00 00
[  514.140860] RIP  [<ffffffff8137c33b>] tcp_v4_destroy_sock+0xdb/0x1c0
[  514.140860]  RSP <ffff88007d00bdb8>
```

When a user-space program calls a system call like `sys_close`, the kernel's `system_call_fastpath` function is called to handle the request. In this particular case, a segmentation fault occurred in the `tcp_v4_destroy_sock()` function, which was called by `tcp_close()` in the kernel code.

While the segfault in `tcp_v4_destroy_sock()` is not enough to crash the entire system, it can cause the process that triggered the segfault to crash or become unresponsive. In this scenario, the `redacted` process that made the system call would likely be affected, but the rest of the system would continue to function normally.

Comment: I just answered what the "segfault" and "general protection faults" are. So your question leads me to respond if the user-mode space program can cause system-wide failure. Let me know if you have any specific questions/concerns that need answering.

Comment: Specifically my question is whether a crash inside `system_call_fastpath()` could occur on a system where the only problem is a bug that is present in a user-space program.

Comment: Updated. Did I answer your question as expected? @JeremyFriesner

Comment: it's close -- in your answer you state `Yea, if a bug in a user-space program causes a crash that happens to occur within the kernel's system_call_fastpath() function [...]` ... but the crux of the question is, *can* a bug in a user-space program cause a crash that way?  I was under the impression that Linux system calls were expected to validate their arguments well enough that such a thing was not allowed to happen, and therefore if such a thing does happen that indicates a kernel-level issue.

Comment: You're right about expecting the Linux kernel to validate their arguments to prevent such a thing. However, it's still possible for a bug in a user-space program to trigger an invalid or unexpected request that the kernel cannot handle. In the end, when I say "kernel debugging," you must find the root cause to confirm "what" is causing this unexpected behavior, as many things CAN (possibility to) cause such behavior: race conditions, resource exhaustion, interference between kernel modules, incorrect error handling, and many other factors that can contribute to kernel-level issues.

Comment: To clarify: It's not that a bug in a user-space program causes a crash in the `system_call_fastpath()` function directly, but rather that a bug in the program can trigger an invalid or unexpected system call request that the kernel is unable to handle, leading to a crash.